# How to use aircrack-ng without wifi adapter or are there any other hacking methods without wireless adapter?

Tags: kali-linux, aircrack-ng

**Question**

I've been trying for eons figuring how to get Kali Linux to work without a wifi adapter because I don't have one.

I tried to use aircrack-ng but it keeps on giving cannot access /sys/class/ieee80211.

What does that mean?

*Btw*

I am using Virtual Box to run Kali Linux.

**In the case that doesnt work**

Should I use rufus to boot Kali Linux on a PC? If i do would that mean that the old OS is gone or can i boot that back?

Comment: How can you test something you don't have?  Note that running it on a regular computer with wifi can be difficult for some, so trying to make it work on a VM is a step above (2 steps above your reach right now).

Comment: Question unclear. What would you use aircrack for without a wifi-card? Or are you asking about dualboot setup/installation with a bootloader called `rufus`?

Comment: @AlexStragies so if i use rufus and boot it into Kali Linux, can i go back to windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

"Aircrack-ng is a complete suite of tools to assess WiFi network security." - https://www.aircrack-ng.org/

If you can't access WiFi networks you can't use Aircrack.

WiFi adapters are relatively cheap on eBay.